# React Trouble updating state with useReducer

Tags: reactjs, state

Utilizing React useReducer and attempting to do state update and have react re-render as I make changes.

JSX calling the reducer:

```
<button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "DECREMENT", item })} >+</button>
```

and the useReducer:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  const { item, type } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case "INCREMENT": {
      const newCart = state;
      const u = { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 };
      const index = newCart.findIndex(eachitem => item.id === eachitem.id);
      newCart.splice(index, 1, u);
      console.log("INCREMENT", newCart);
      return newCart;
    }
    case "DECREMENT": {
      const newCart = state;
      const u = { ...item, quantity: item.quantity - 1 };
      const index = newCart.findIndex(eachitem => item.id === eachitem.id);
      newCart.splice(index, 1, u);
      console.log("DECREMENT", newCart);
      return newCart;
    }
    case "REMOVE": {
      return state.filter(eachitem => item.id !== eachitem.id);
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

Full code can be found below.

[image: Edit codesandboxer-example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reducer can't detect the state change since you return the same object. The change is detected by comparing prev state value and new one, by `===` comparison or [`Object.is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) comparison which is basically the same thing (not sure which one, can try to find in React docs).

So instead of:

```
const newCart = state;
```

You need to do:

```
// shallowly copy the state so now Object.is(newState, prevState) returns false
const newCart = [...state];
...
return newCart
```

Comment: This looks better than returning a new object 

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I created NewCart to avoid mutating, but because it's an object it is points to the same object (and I was mutating it). By spreading state into new object, it gives  a shallow copy and actually references a new object. Thx

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `newCart` as the state, which point to the same thing.
Either you clone the state, or return a new object instance.

```
switch (type) {
    case "INCREMENT": {
      const newCart = state;
      const u = { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 };
      const index = newCart.findIndex(eachitem => item.id === eachitem.id);
      newCart.splice(index, 1, u);
      console.log("INCREMENT", newCart);

      return [...newCart];
    }
    case "DECREMENT": {
      const newCart = state;
      const u = { ...item, quantity: item.quantity - 1 };
      const index = newCart.findIndex(eachitem => item.id === eachitem.id);
      newCart.splice(index, 1, u);
      console.log("DECREMENT", newCart);
      return [...newCart];
    }
    case "REMOVE": {
      return state.filter(eachitem => item.id !== eachitem.id);
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

**Updated SandBox**
[image: Edit codesandboxer-example]